# Функця getopt(): необходимо параметру передать два аргумента

Tags: c, getopt

Необходимо в функцию getopt() передать параметру -s два аргумента (координаты точки).

```
./myfunc -s 2.5 7.3
```

Эта задача легко реализуется, если передавать аргументы в виде строки:

```
./myfunc -s "2.5 7.3"
```

Но этот вариант забракован.
Обработчик getopt() реализован на языке C. Использование функции getopt() - must

И второй вопрос на эту же тему.
Фунция getopt(). Задан шаблон входных данных "s:", т.е. обязателен аргумент для этого параметра. Но задача заключается в том, что аргумент может быть, а может и не быть. Как обработать эту ситуацию?

```
./111: option requires an argument -- 's'
```

Comment: Все верно, моя программа. Но ее необходимо выполнить при таких начальных условиях. Т.е параметры не должны быть "окавычены". Заказчик )
Вы правы, если задать аргументы без пробела, то весь набор символов будет воспринят как строка. Как вариант норм.

Comment: Что скажете про такой синтаксис `./myfunc -s 2.5,7.3` ?